# Конвертирование строки в дату

Tags: c#

Есть проблема. В файле я храню дату и в зависимости от настроек CultureInfo формат хранения в виде строки отличен. К примеру
*12/11/2017 10:07:48 AM* (первый вариант en-US)
*11.12.2017 10:07:48* (второй вариант )

Это одна и та же дата и время !!!

Конвертирую из строки в DateTime обычным методом. Со вторым вариантом проблем нет, но вот как сконвертировать корректно первый вариант, ведь в начале идет месяц, а потом день?

Comment: "В файле я храню дату и в зависимости от настроек CultureInfo" - не храните в зависимости, храните независимо.

Comment: @Igor прав. Не нужно смешивать данные и их отображение. Если же по какой-то причине это строго необходимо, храни вместе с датой ещё и культуру, указывай её при парсинге. Две культуры могут отличаться только порядком DD/MM и MM/DD, поэтому определить культуру по формату в общем случае ты не можешь, как и передать несколько возможных форматов - высока вероятность ошибки. Если речь о ru/us культурах, конечно, ты можешь использовать, как явное указание формата, так и явное указание культуры. Но это явно не лучшая мысль.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите.
У вас везде для показа пользователю должна использоваться `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`, а для хранения в текстовом виде (например, в файле) — `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

Так делается потому, что пользователь-то хочет видеть данные в том формате, в каком ему интересно, а вот для записи в файл нужен формат, который переживёт смену пользователем языка, открытие документа другим пользователем и даже перенос на другой компьютер.

Comment: В общем, не могу понять. Воспользовался вашим советом. Теперь первый вариант выглядит так: 12/11/2017 10:07:48 Второй вариант выглядит вот так 11/12/2017 10:07:48 Не пойму почему изменятся порядок дня и месяца...

Comment: //Нашел свою ошибку.

Comment: @АлександрПузанов: Ага, вот и хорошо. А в чём была ошибка?

Comment: Совет отличный. В потоке для записи в файл я написал CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, для чтения тоже нужно (не подумал вначале), потому что в основном потоке я установил CultureInfo.CurrentCulture... Серьезно, так и буду делать в будущем, потому что промучался целый день с этим.

Comment: @АлександрПузанов: А, ну да. Так и надо. Хорошо, что разобрались!